# Comment utiliser le passé composé et l'imparfait en présence d'une indication de temps supplémentaire ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, indications-de-temps, passé-composé, imparfait

Pour préciser ma question, je voulais savoir l'emploi de ces deux temps dans les exemples suivants.

1. 2008-maintenant à Paris. Que dit-on ?

   A. *J'ai habité à Paris depuis 2008, et j'habite encore à Paris.*

   B. *J'ai habité à Paris pendant six ans, et j'habite encore à Paris.*

   C. *J'habitais à Paris depuis 2008, et j'habite encore à Paris.*
2. 2008-2010 à Paris, 2011-maintenant à Lyon. Que dit-on ?

   A. *J'ai habité à Paris depuis 2008, mais j'habite maintenant à Lyon.*

   B. *J'ai habité à Paris pendant trois ans, et j'habite maintenant à Lyon.*

   C. *J'habitais à Paris depuis 2008, mais j'habite maintenant à Lyon.*

J'ai cherché la différence sur google, ça m'a beaucoup aidé, mais je suis encore confus par les exemples que j'ai imaginés plus haut.

PS: Il y a une synthèse sur l'aspect qui est très utile sur le site http://bouche-a-oreille.pagesperso-orange.fr/grammaire/aspect.htm. Mais je ne sais pas comment envisager l'action de l'intérieur et de l'extérieur. Cela veut dire que le narrateur fait partie de la scène qu'il raconte?

Comment: Dans ce cas ce qui t'intéresse c'est l'aspect accompli/non accompli qui est à considérer. Tu as oublié de considérer le présent. Regarde [ici aussi](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/les-valeurs-demploi-des-temps-simples-de-lindicatif.html).

Comment: Merci pour ce lien, dans ce cas. Pour le 1er exemple, on dit C (non accompli, car j'habite encore à Paris)au lieu de A et B? Pour le 2e exemple, on dit B (accompli)au lieu de A et C? Je suis pas sûr si tous les 3 dans les 2 exemples sont corrects.

Comment: 1- oui, C. 2- Oui, B - mais je pense qu'on pourrait imaginer un contexte particulier pour C. par exemple J'habitais à Paris depuis 2008 quand j'ai déménagé pour Lyon où je vis encore. Mais telle quelle ta phrase sonne bizarre sans vraiment être incorrecte.

Comment: Je rectifie ce que je disais : C ne va pas, dans les deux cas à cause du "depuis".  "J'habitais à Paris **en** 2008 et j'habite encore à Paris / mais j’habite maintenant (désormais) à Lyon."

Comment: C'est très clair. La raison pour laquelle C ne va pas vient-elle du fait que "depuis" sert à préciser le début d'une durée, alors que l'imparfait ne supporte pas une durée définie? Une autre question, le point de vue intérieure et extérieure de l'action, je ne le comprends pas. [Ici](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/n10/cdm2.htm), on a une caméra et un appareil photo. Cela veut dire que si nous sommes dans une caméra, nous sommes à l'intérieure et à l'extérieure si dans un appareil photo?

Comment: Je trouve ces dessins pas très heureux et trompeurs et c'est normal que tu ne comprennes pas. Laisse tomber les dessins.

Answer (score 12):

#### Passé composé

> J'ai habité à Paris...

Veut dire que je n'y habite plus au moment où je parle.

On utilise le **passé composé** pour exprimer un fait accompli dans le moment présent, c'est-à-dire que, lors de l'énonciation, l'événement exprimé par le verbe est achevé.

#### Imparfait de l'indicatif

> J'habitais à Paris....

Ne va pas exprimer une durée mais situer l'action par rapport à une autre, on attend une suite qui va situer l'action, par exemple

> J'habitais à Paris quand j'ai passé mon bac.

On utilise **l'imparfait** pour exprimer une action non achevée et d'une durée non définie par rapport à une autre action.

#### Présent de l'indicatif

> J'habite à Paris.

Veut dire qu'en ce moment j'habite à Paris et si je l'emploie avec une expression de durée :

> J'habite à Paris depuis 2008.

Sert à dire depuis combien de temps j'y habite.

On dit parfois que le **présent de l'indicatif** a un pied dans le passé et un pied dans le futur, tout dépend du contexte.

> [Le présent est d'aspect inaccompli et sécant : on n'envisage pas les limites d'un événement, le procès est envisagé en cours d'accomplissement.](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/les-valeurs-demploi-des-temps-simples-de-lindicatif.html)

#### Donc:

- > J'habite à Paris depuis 2008.

Veut dire que je suis arrivé à Paris en 2008 et que j'y habite encore, inutile d'en dire plus.

- 

> J’habite à Lyon depuis 2011. Avant j'ai habité à Paris pendant trois ans.
>   
>   Passé composé car la durée est précisée.

- > J’habite à Lyon depuis 2011. Avant j'habitais à Paris.

Imparfait car la durée n'est pas précisée.

- > J'ai habité à Paris de 2008 à 2010, et depuis que j'ai quitté Paris je vis à Lyon.

J'ai quitté : passé composé car l'action est datée.

Bien sûr je n'ai mentionné les valeurs des temps que par rapport aux exemples donnés, ils ont tous bien d'autres valeurs.
Cette page est aussi très claire : [Le temps et l'aspect](http://bv.alloprof.qc.ca/francais/les-classes-de-mots/le-verbe/la-conjugaison-des-verbes/le-temps-et-l%27aspect.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Je conseille la lecture de cet article qui donne des explications très exhaustives sur l'utilisation de "depuis" + passé composé

http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/igram_0222-9838_1999_num_80_1_3567

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenue, Paola, merci pour ta réponse. L'article semble intéressant en effet, mais peut-être pourrais-tu nous en résumer la teneur ? Le lien permettra alors à tous d'aller voir le détail.