# Elle a beaucoup éternué / éternuait beaucoup cette fin de semaine

Tags: passé-composé, imparfait

> Elle **a** beaucoup **éternué** cette fin de semaine (ou ce weekend).
>
> Elle **éternuait** beaucoup cette fin de semaine.

D'après ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8901/comment-utiliser-le-pass%C3%A9-compos%C3%A9-et-limparfait-en-pr%C3%A9sence-dune-indication-de), seule la phrase avec le passé composé est correcte en raison du *fin de semain*e. Pourtant, à mon avis, la deuxième phrase devrait aussi être acceptable ; pour moi, il s'agit d'une description, et le fait que je mentionne la fin de semaine n'a guère d'importance.

Pourquoi l'imparfait est-il incorrect ici ?

Comment: Je ne trouve pas "fin de semaine" dans le fil. Pourrais-tu nous signalé oú cela se trouve, stp.

Answer (score 1):

On ne s'attend pas à trouver l'imparfait dans une phrase sans suite explicite ou implicite. Dans le fil en question, les deux exemples impliquent bien une suite:

> On utilise l'imparfait pour exprimer une action non achevée et d'une durée non définie par rapport à une autre action.

Tu pourrais écrire par exemple :

> Elle éternuait beaucoup le weekend dernier, mais depuis, ça s'est bien calmé.

Comment: _les deux exemples impliquent une suite_ Je ne comprends pas. Non, il n'y a pas de suite dans la 2ème phrase _J’habite à Lyon depuis 2011. Avant j'habitais à Paris._ // _On ne s'attend pas à trouver l'imparfait dans une phrase à un seul verbe_ Justement, je ne comprends pas pourquoi. À mon avis, _Elle **éternuait** beaucoup  ce samedi_ devrait être possible, ce serait une description.

Comment: Il y a bien une suite dans la deuxième phrase. Il se trouve qu'elle est située avant (*j'habite à Lyon depuis 2011*) mais techniquement, c'est bien un événement postérieur.

Comment: Après réflexion, il n'y a pas forcément besoin d'une autre phrase ou d'un autre verbe. Par exemple la phrase  *Avant, j'avais pas la fibre* se suffit à elle même. La présence du mot *Avant* justifie l'imparfait et entraîne la suite implicite sous-entendue *et maintenant, je l'ai*. Dans ta phrase, ce serait: *Le weekend dernier, elle éternuait beaucoup*.

Comment: J'ai l'impression que toutes les informations que j'avais lues auparavant se sont mélangés dans ma tête. :( Dans ta réponse, il est écrit que _On utilise l'imparfait pour exprimer une action non achevée et d'une **durée non définie**_, mais dans ta phrase  _**Le weekend dernier**, elle éternuait beaucoup_, la durée est définie, c'est le weekend dernier. Puis, pourquoi la phrase _Le weekend dernier, elle éternuait beaucoup_ est possible alors que la mienne _Elle éternuait beaucoup cette fin de semaine_ non ? Quelle est la différence entre ces deux phrases ?

Comment: Si je traduit de l'anglais **vers le français**,  j'aurais ceci They were dancing a lot on the weekend. [now they are not dancing] contre: They danced a lot on the weekend. Wouldn't that be: ils dansaient versus ils ont dansé? Une durée non définie peut se trouver à l'intérieur d'une période de temps définie. Non?

Comment: *Le weekend dernier* indique quand ça s'est passé mais reste imprécis quant à la durée de la période où elle éternuait. Je n'ai pas dit que la phrase était "impossible", juste que je perçois une impression d'inachevé dans *elle éternuait beaucoup ce weekend* alors qu'avec *elle a beaucoup éternué ce weekend*, le message est complet.

Answer (score 1):

Le participe passé (éternué) vise à décrire une action passée dont on ne précise pas si elle est finie.
L'imparfait, lui, marque une action dans une période dépassée.
La bonne formulation dépend de l'instant où on veut se placer dans la description du récit.

Comment: Merci. Donc, _elle a éternué ce samedi_ signifie qu'il est possible qu'elle continue à éternuer et qu'elle éternue peut-être aussi aujourd'hui ? Et _elle éternuait ce samedi_ veut dire qu'elle n'éternue plus ?